# Integrating kaltura search with alfresco share?

Tags: search, alfresco, kaltura

I have an alfresco share which has its own simple/advanced search. Also i have kaltura video engine to manage videos.

I want to know how can i customize my alfresco search so that i can search kaltura for videos from alfresco share UI without going to kaltura.

Regards.

Comment: Did you already see this integration from Jeff Potts and others? http://www.kaltura.org/project/Alfresco_Extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working.

I used kaltura supplied jars to call functionalities from alfresco where i created actions/rules to upload videos in kaltura from alfresco share.

It was fun implementing it.

Regards.